# I can't understand why my express route is encountering 'can't set headers after they are sent'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to make a Machine Learning Project(An Integer Sequence Predictor). ML code is a python script. I am trying to make a express route to handle the stdin and stdout of the python script and send response according to that.

I am spawning the python script as the app starts.

```
let p = spawn('python', ['python/script.py'], { stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', process.stderr] });
```

**My Route**

```
router.get('/', managePredictor);
```

**managePredictor**

```
    function managePredictor(req, res, next) {
  try {
    //timestamp
    let ts = new Date().getTime();
    let token = ts + '_' + magic();
    let seq = req.query.seq;
    let re = new RegExp(token + '((?:\\s|\\S)*)' + token);
    p.stdin.write(token + '\n' + seq + '\n');
    p.stdout.resume();
    p.stdout.on('data', (chunk) => {
      str += chunk;
      let s = re.exec(str);
      let o = JSON.parse(s[1].trim());
      p.stdout.pause();
      res.send(o);
    });
  }
  catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  }
}
```

`token` is a string like `1520661269162_YGo6p3`.

For first request to the route but for any consectutive request the error is like

```
>Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
>    at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:494:11)
>    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:501:3)
>    at ServerResponse.header (D:\mlproj\node_modules\express
>lib\response.js:730:10)
>    at ServerResponse.send (D:\mlproj\node_modules\express >\lib\response.js:170:12)
>    at ServerResponse.json (D:\mlproj\node_modules\express >\lib\response.js:256:15)
>    at ServerResponse.send (D:\mlproj\node_modules\express >\lib\response.js:158:21)
at Socket.p.stdout.on (D:\mlproj\routes\predict.js:39:11)
at emitOne (events.js:121:20)
at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
```

**Python Script's IO snippet**

```
while True:
ts = input()
inp = input()
arr = inp.split(" ")
arr = list(map(lambda x: int(x), arr))
qq = findNextn(arr, 5)
print(ts)
out = json.dumps({'orignal': arr, 'predicted':qq}, indent=4)
print(out)
print(ts)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> p.stdout.on('data', (chunk) => {
>    ...
>    res.send(o);
> ```

You try to send a response every time you get a chunk of data.

So the first time you get a chunk of data after the request arrives, you send a response.

Then the next time you get a chunk of data, you try to send the response again. You can't do that because it has already been sent.

---

You need to rethink your approach to how you handle the interaction between HTTP requests and the data from the Python program.

Possibly you should be storing the data in a string each time you get a chunk from the Python process, and then responding to HTTP requests with the current content of that string (while resetting it back to an empty one).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [node streams](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/node-js-streams-everything-you-need-to-know-c9141306be93) for this.

The following code should work.

```
function managePredictor(req, res, next) {
    try {
    //timestamp
    let ts = new Date().getTime();
    let token = ts + '_' + magic();
    let seq = req.query.seq;
    let re = new RegExp(token + '((?:\\s|\\S)*)' + token);
    p.stdin.write(token + '\n' + seq + '\n');
    p.stdout.on('open', () => {
      res.pipe(p.stdout)
    })
    p.stdout.on('data', (chunk) => {
      str += chunk;
      let s = re.exec(str);
      let o = JSON.parse(s[1].trim());
      p.stdout.write(o);
    });
    p.stdout.on('end', (chunk) => {
     res.end();
    });
  }
  catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  }
}
```

Comment: This won't work in my case as I am not spawning the python process for every but I am trying to work upon stdin/stdout of an already spawned process which gets spawned once the app starts

Comment: This should still work for you. What's the error you are getting?

Comment: `Invalid data, chunk must be a string or buffer, not object`

Comment: Ok it should be a string

Comment: Now after correcting the error, I am never getting a response. Maybe because in my python script is running forever expecting I/O that's why this streams shouldn't work as the stdout ends with the app is terminated. So I need to find some other solution.